# What is this code for?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand what this code is for, but I can't figure. Could You explain it to me?

```
co_to(I, I, [I]).

co_to(I, L, [I|L]) :- I < K, I1 is I + 1, co_to(I1, K, L).
```

Comment: That code is wrong. Second clause uses comparison operator < with uninstantiated variable K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As gusbro pointed out in his comment, this code doesn't work. But if you change the head of the second clause to

```
co_to(I, K, [I|L]) :- ...
```

then it generates for a goal `co_to(X,Y,L)` a list `L` of numbers ranging from `X` to `Y`, e.g.:

```
?- co_to(5,10,L).
L = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
No (0.02s cpu)
```

Comment: Thank you twinterer, that helped a lot!